# Text to speech not working on incoming call in marshmallow

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

This code works perfect up to Lollipop devices, but it is not working on any Marshmallow device. I have tried many things, like:

1) changed STREAM_MUSIC to STREAM_RING

2) changed STREAM_MUSIC to STREAM_SYSTEM

3) Blocked ringtone on incoming call for playing tts

But none of these worked.

```
          @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                private void ttsUnder20(String text) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "MessageId");

                        speech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map); //speak for API level<21
                    }


                enter code here
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                private void ttsGreater21(String text) {
                    bund.clear();
                    String utteranceId = this.hashCode() + "";
                    audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volume, 0);
                    //
                    // audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);


                        bund.putInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        speech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, bund, "");
                    }



//check for read phone state permission when activity start.
 private void checkPermission() {
        // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
    }
```

**Any help would be Appreciated.**

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` Maybe APIs you're using are deprecated now? Remove this.

Comment: thanks for your comment. but in case of marshamallow it will go to ttsGreater21 method. dont know why it,s not speaking

Comment: Are you asking for permission for RECORD_AUDIO inside your Manifest and also doing the runtime permission check when using the microphone?

Comment: @AdamGardner just assume that i am not using microphone.so program will go in else condition. but it is not speaking on incoming call even i am providing READ_PHONE_STATE permission at run time.

Comment: You're saying the Text-To-Speech is not working on Marshmellow devices which might be that the app isn't checking the runtime permissions. Usually, if anything I have done works on all OS versions except Marshmellow, it's because I didn't check the runtime permission.

Comment: Do you have this in your manifest Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO? Then on the click of your icon to bring up the speech to text UI have this check if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
            REQUEST_MICROPHONE);

}

Comment: @AdamGardner I have  updated my code.  please have look at this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137157/discussion-between-mubashshir-and-adam-gardner).